# Change applied in database but DbContext does not show

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ninject

I have an asp.net webapi hosted using OWin and I use ninject for DI. Here is how I inject `DbContext`:

```
kernel.Bind<IAuthRepository>().To<AuthRepository>();
kernel.Bind<AuthDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

I have a repository class that I use the context as below:

```
private AuthDbContext _ctx { get; set; }    

public AuthRepository(AuthDbContext ctx)
{
    _ctx = ctx;
}
```

There is this method in repository that I call to change some data:

```
var res = await _ctx
    .Clients
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(clientEntity => clientEntity.UserRef.Id == p);

//do the modification
_ctx.Entry(res).State = EntityState.Modified;

_ctx.SaveChanges();

return res;
```

It saves the data correctly in db, but after, when I call another action and get that saved entity, I see that changes are not in the context.

```
public async Task<Client> FindClientById(Guid clientId)
{
    return await _ctx
        .Clients
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(clientEntity => clientEntity.Id == clientId);
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is saving to database correctly? Have you checked? Also, in the first function you search for `clientEntity.UserRef.Id == p` and the second it is `clientEntity.Id == clientId`, are you sure these both refer to the same thing?

Comment: yes I checked the databse and yes they  point to same recorde

Comment: When you do the search and find the first result in the clients table; what data are you modifying?

Comment: Hi @Son_of_Sam I solved the issue using NH over ASP.NET Identity